# copy rows with special condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a lot of columns. For example I have a table with these columns :

```
ID,Fname,Lname,Tel,Mob,Email,Job,Code,Company,......
```

`ID` column is auto number column. I want to copy all rows in this table to this table and change the `company` column value to 12 in this copied row. I don't want to write name all of the columns because I have a lot of table with a lot of columns.

I tried this code but I had this error :

```
declare @c int;
declare @i int;

select * into CmDet from CmDet;
select @C= count(id) from CmDet;

while @i < @C
begin
UPDATE CmDet
SET company =12
WHERE company=11
set @i += 1
end
```

error :

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 3
>   There is already an object named 'CmDet' in the database.

I changed the code to this

```
declare @c int
declare @i int
insert into CmDet select * from CmDet;
select @C= count(id) from CmDet;
while @i < @C
begin
UPDATE CmDet
SET company =12
WHERE company=11
set @i += 1
end
```

and I had this error :

> Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 3   An explicit value for the
>   identity column in table 'CmDet' can only be specified when a column
>   list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

What should I do ?

---

i write this code :

```
drop table temp2;
declare @c bigint ;
select @C= count(id) from CmDet2;
SELECT * 
INTO temp2
FROM CmDet2;
ALTER TABLE temp2
     drop column ID;
update temp2 set company='12';
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.CmDet2 ON
insert into CmDet2 select * from temp2;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.CmDet2 OFF;
```

but i have this error yet :

Msg 545, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'CmDet2' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column.

Comment: You are copying from one table into the same table? Well, you'll have to use `INSERT INTO dbo.CmDet(company, col1, col2, ...., colN) SELECT 12, col1, col2, ..., colN FROM dbo.CmDet WHERE Company = 11` in order to achieve this. Also: you need to make sure to **avoid** specifying the `ID` (identity) column - since you cannot insert values into that column - SQL Server takes care of that.....

Comment: You can easily create a list of all your table's columns by using [this handy tip by Mitch Wheat](http://mitch-wheat.blogspot.com/2011/04/ssms-table-column-list-tip.html) - and then just remove those columns you don't need (`ID`)

Comment: yes i want to copy into same table . but i don't want to write the columns name  because i have a lot of tables with a lot of columns . and i wanna write a query , and change the table name and exec .

Comment: See my tip just above your comment - you will **have to** spell out the columns - one way or another .

Comment: You *need* to write the column names. Anything other than that is a recipe for disaster. Use your Management Studio to get the list of columns and just copy/paste. Right click table, script, select, new window. go.

Comment: You have made it clear that the ID column is auto-incremental. That alone should give you enough clues as to why it doesn't work. Values in an identity column are UNIQUE. It matters not whether you have identity_insert on. List out all the columns and leave out the identity column.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert into a table that already exists.  I would suggest, either dropping the `CmDet` table and then re-running your first query (if the purpose of the table is to store temporary data).  Or, you can use:

`SET IDENTITY_INSERT CmDet ON;`

Which will allow you to insert explicit values into the identity column of the table.

Comment: yeah - but then he'll start copying **duplicate values** into his `ID` column! Not a good idea......

Comment: I agree, but until we know if `CmDet` is purely a `temp` table, I'm just firing out options.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to insert "copied" rows and also replacing the company value with 12. don't include the ID column in your list, but replace a,b,c,d,e with proper column names. Use the same list in the `SELECT` statement, ***except Company!***.

```
INSERT  INTO TBL
        ( a,
          b,
          c,
          d,
          e,
          company
        )
        SELECT
            a,
            b,
            c,
            d,
            e,
            12 AS company
        FROM
            TBL
        WHERE
            1=1
            -- Include the following line if you only want specific rows (company 11)
            AND company = 11
```